# Why Isn't AddClass being included after clicking a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to understand this, I have the following code(a bit messy, starting off with javascript) that I've been working on, I made it work with a toggle menu and it works perfectly for the `first li drop down`, but for the other three it doesn't, I want to know how I can fix this?

There are 4 drop downs that works with .click, and `only the first one` activates the **AddClass**..

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mobileFirst").click(function(e) {
        $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(3)").click(function(e)
    {
        $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) .menu-sub").toggle(function(){
            if ($('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block")
            {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(3)").addClass("li-bottom-fix");
            } else {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(3)").removeClass("li-bottom-fix");
            }
        });
    });

    $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(4)").click(function(e)
    {
        $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(4) .menu-sub").toggle(function(){
            if ($('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block")
            {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(4)").addClass("li-bottom-fix");
            } else {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(4)").removeClass("li-bottom-fix");
            }
        });
    });

    $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(6)").click(function(e)
    {
        $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(6) .menu-sub").toggle(function(){
            if ($('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block")
            {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(6)").addClass("li-bottom-fix");
            } else {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(6)").removeClass("li-bottom-fix");
            }
        });
    });
    $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(7)").click(function(e)
    {
        $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(7) .menu-sub").toggle(function(){
            if ($('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block")
            {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(7)").addClass("li-bottom-fix");
            } else {
                $(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(7)").removeClass("li-bottom-fix");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I haven't included any HTML because as I said, it clearly adds the **li-bottom-fix** to the first button, but for the other three it doesn't.

Comment: `$('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block"` will always compare the `display` CSS style of the **first** `.menu-sub` element in the document. From the [`.css` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/): *"Get the value of a computed style property for the **first** element in the set of matched elements [...]"*

Comment: Off topic because "why isn't this code working?"

Comment: @FelixKling, that makes a lot of sense.. thank you for clearing that up for me. I though considering the fact that it was choosing the specific li with nth-of-type it would only focus on the child elements.

Comment: @bhspencer: "why isn't this code working?" is not automatically off-topic.

Comment: @FelixKling true but they are off topic when "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers" which is clearly the case here.

Comment: The OP just dumped a bunch of broken code. There is very little chance that this question will be of any use to any one else ever.

Comment: I completely disagree to that one, his answer will surely help as It has helped me with other issues already. Nonetheless, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.menu-sub').css("display") == "block"
```

will always compare the `display` CSS style of the **first** `.menu-sub` element in the document. From the [`.css` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements [...]

If you want to refer to the element you called `toggle` on, use `this`:

```
$(this).css("display") == "block"
```

From the [`.toggle` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but `this` is set to the DOM element being animated.

---

And instead of repeating the selector instead the handler, just keep a reference to the clicked element:

```
$(".mobile-menu > .menu-container > ul > li:nth-of-type(3)").click(function(e) {
    var $clickedElement = $(this);
    $clickedElement.find(".menu-sub").toggle(function() {
        $clickedElement.toggleClass(
          "li-bottom-fix", 
          $(this).css("display") === "block"
        );
    });
});
```

If you can, you should give all those elements the same class so that you don't have to repeat the logic. At least name the event handler and reuse it (now that it is generalized).